# Change date after SSH login in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have to change the date after an SSH login into machine, but I am not able to change it. Here is the script I have written:

```
#!/bin/bash
ENVIRONMENT_LIST=environment_ip_list
USERNAME=root
declare ENVIRONMENT_ARRAY

mdate="$#"

readIp()
{
while read IP
    do
        ENVIRONMENT_ARRAY[$env_count]="$IP"
        let env_count++
    done < $ENVIRONMENT_LIST
}
change_date()
{
    for ((i = 0; i < env_count; i++))
    do
        ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USERNAME@${ENVIRONMENT_ARRAY[i]} "'date -s "$1 $2 $3 $4"'"
    done
}
readIp
change_date
```

In a terminal, I get this output:

```
~/Desktop/changedate_script $ ./change.sh 04 SEP 2012 10:36:00
root@192.168.12.160's password: 
bash: date -s  : command not found
Connection to 192.168.12.160 closed.
```

Comment: If that is about setting correct time, why not to use ntp?

Comment: yeah but i want to try date command along with ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many quotes in ssh command.

Use the following one:

```
 ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USERNAME@${ENVIRONMENT_ARRAY[i]} "date -s '$1 $2 $3 $4'"
```

also change tsring with change_date function call to:

```
change_date $1 $2 $3 $4
```

Comment: i changed in above manner but got diff results its is not changin to the date i am mentioning            ./change.sh 04 SEP 2013 10:36:00
root@192.168.12.160's password: 
Tue Sep  4 00:00:00 IST 2012
Connection to 192.168.12.160 closed.

Comment: ah, it looks like your function knows nothing about script parameters. change function call like in updated answer.